# String Formatter for string constants in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, logging, constants, format-specifiers

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I tried searching around including Apple's [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html), and [IEEE printf spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) but couldn't find the answer for something this simple.

I would like to print os_log message with string formatter for string constant. Something akin to:

```
printf("Currently at processing state: %s\n", "reading in");
```

in C. However, when I tried something like this in Swift:

```
os_log("Currently at processing state: %s", log: .default, type: .info, "reading in")
```

it simply printed nothing out at all.

How do I print a string constant using string format specifier? I'm not sure how to do it with `NSLog` either.

Edit: `os_log` requires `StaticString`, so it can't do something like `"Something \(Expr) Something else"` like in `print()`. You can still use string formatting to print number variables. I'm wondering how to print string constants / variables in this case.

Edit 2: Apple actually has discussion on this topic right on its [manual page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/logging?language=objc), which I managed to miss it because but it's only discussed in the Objective-C API version for now.

Comment: "something \\(any swift expression) something else"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the `os_log` man page:

> You may also use the "%@" format specifier for use with Obj-C/CF/Swift objects

In your case

```
import os.log

os_log("Currently at processing state: %@", log: .default, type: .info, "reading in")
```

works because the Swift string is bridged to `NSString` on a 
variable argument list.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score -5):

This will work:

```
print("Currently at processing state: \(readingin)")
```

So you put the parameter you want to print for readingin.

(If this solved your question please mark it as the answer)

Comment: I'm looking for an answer for `os_log` which requires string format specifiers for `StaticString` to print out value of a variable.